# Same distance from AnchorPane to AnchorPane

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

I created this GUI in Scene Builder. I have an AnchorPane on an AnchorPane, but how do I get it to the edge of the same distance? See second picture. Up, down, right, left should be the same distance from the red AnchorPane everywhere.

[image]

[image]

Comment: i'll try to explain as an answer below

Comment: You should do more research on the different `Parent` nodes. Just looking at what you got so far lends itself to many problems. If a font change or the screen resolution change, you are going to have stuff here and there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-So first thing you need to do, is to choose the layout you want to adjust (the blue one).

-Under the Inspecter panel on the right, you choose the "Layout" pane

-Finally you set the disired values under Anchor Pane Constraints. (they need to have all the same value)

You can ignore all the steps and edit your FXML file :

```
<AnchorPane layoutX="31.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" style="-fx-background-color: blue;" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="ENTER_THE_VALUE" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="ENTER_THE_VALUE" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="ENTER_THE_VALUE" AnchorPane.topAnchor="ENTER_THE_VALUE" />
```